# Filter out path strings beginning with strings

Tags: c#

I have a collection of paths (e.g. `C:\Users`, `C:\Users\cheese`, `D:\Shadow\stuff` ,`D:\Shadow`). Is there any way to get rid of strings that are lesser path? e.g. to only leave `C:\Users\cheese` and `D:\Shadow\stuff` and make it FAST and memory un-intensive?

It is important that the strings can come in any order.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. Is your solution too slow? Eating too much memory? How many strings do you intend to support? I like the motto: Make it work, make it right, make it fast.

Comment: It is possible, if you can define `lesser path`.

Comment: Why not count the back-slashes?

Comment: @Erno because `C:\Foo\Bar\Baz` _probably_ shouldn't replace `C:\Bar`, but I'd love to see OP answer @oleksii. Also with @Ed, removing a few string probably isn't going to make your application any noticeable faster or less memory-intensive.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah, yes that makes sense. So remove all parent paths for the collection.

Comment: @oleksii the wording was pretty bad on my part, it should've been path closest to the root. (e.g. C:\Users is less in length than C:\Users\cheese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would order paths in descending way, and then just skip sub-paths when enumerating collection of paths and adding them to results:

```
string[] paths = { @"C:\Users", @"C:\Users\cheese", @"D:\Shadow\stuff", @"D:\Shadow" };

string currentPath = "";
List<string> result = new List<string>();
var comparer = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;

foreach (var path in paths.OrderByDescending(p => p, comparer))
{
    if (currentPath.IndexOf(path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        continue;

    result.Add(path);
    currentPath = path;
}
```

Result:

```
[
  "D:\\Shadow\\stuff",
  "C:\\Users\\cheese"
]
```

Comment: This seems great. Do you know if a similar approach is also possible in T-SQL?

Comment: upd: I re-implemented the same algorithm with cursors and CHARINDEX(). Now for some profiling again.